# How do I roll back updates on my MBP?

Tags: snow-leopard, restore, software-update

My MBP has been freezing every day, and extremely slow ever since the last 10.6.8 update. Is there a way to go back to when my laptop was usable? Sort of like in Windows where you can uninstall updates

Comment: If you're experiencing a lot of slowdown, your hard drive may be on the way out. I'd recommend backing up everything ASAP and maybe trying a new drive (they're easy to upgrade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've ruled out other issues (HDD f/ex) and want to roll back to 10.6.7, the quickest way will be to re-install 10.6 followed by the [10.6.7 Combo update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1361).

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X does not have a feature like Windows System Restore Points. Doing this sort of thing on a Mac is considerably more involved and problematic.

That being said, there are other options and workarounds for troubleshooting your system's performance and how to fix it. I'll have to leave that for another post.

Have you been using Time Machine to make complete backups of your Mac to an external hard drive, every hour, every day?

Comment: No :( I don't have a time machine drive per se, but I do backup about once a month everything in my User folder

Comment: Because you don't have a Time Machine backup, and because this is not an obvious problem, it's my opinion that you need to pay a professional to examine your system and determine what is causing the slow-down. It is probably not because of 10.6.8. There is most probably some other cause.